# ObjectQuery<T> without Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, objectquery

How to use `ObjectContext` and `ObjectQuery<T>` with my own classes and objects?

I.e. I don't want to use them with Entity Framework.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ObjectContext and ObjectQuery are the Entity Framework. You could implement your own Custom Linq Provider. A very good example can be found at "THE WAYWARD WEBLOG" http://blogs.msdn.com/mattwar/pages/linq-links.aspx. This Blog helped me implementing my own custom Provider.

```
public interface IQueryable : IEnumerable {       
    Type ElementType { get; }
    Expression Expression { get; }
    IQueryProvider Provider { get; }
}

public interface IQueryProvider {
    IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression);
    IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression);
    object Execute(Expression expression);
    TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression);
}
```